# Does a function with left limits have only countable jumps?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, continuity

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has left limits, does it have at most countable jumps? By the set of jumps of $f$ I mean the set $\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x^-)\neq f(x)\}$

This is indeed true if we add the hypothesis of having also right limits as it was proved in [How much a càdlàg (i.e., right-continuous with left limits) function can jump?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10257/how-much-a-c%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g-i-e-right-continuous-with-left-limits-function-can-jump/10320#10320)
But the proof does use this additional hypothesis.

Any ideas?

Comment: It can have non-jump discontinuities.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, of course. My question is whether $\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x^-)\neq f(x)\}$  is countable. I'll edit my question to make this clearer. Thank you